# SQLDataReader returns nothing but the Query returns 1 Row

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008

i have a SQLQuery and the SQLDataReader doesn't return the result reliably.

here is the query:

```
SELECT b.ID,b.VERANSTALTER, b.SERIENBOOKUID, (select oa.ORIGINALDATE from OUTLOOKADDIN oa where oa.BOOKINGID = b.ID and oa.GUID is null) as ORIGINALDATE , rr.VON ,rr.BIS, b.THEMA, b.STORNO, ra.BEZEICHNUNG, et.BEZEICHNUNG as ETAGE,geb.ADRESSE, st.NAME as STADT 
from BUCHUNG b 
JOIN RESERVIERUNGRAUM rr on rr.BUCHUNG_ID = b.ID 
JOIN RAUM ra on ra.ID = rr.RAUM_ID 
JOIN ETAGE et on et.ID = ra.ETAGE_ID 
JOIN GEBAEUDE geb on geb.ID = ra.GEBAEUDE_ID 
JOIN STADT st on st.ID = ra.STADT_ID 
WHERE b.UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN cast('20140625 20:58:16' as DATETIME) AND getdate() 
AND b.BOOKVERNR = 0 
AND b.ID = (select distinct oa.BOOKINGID from OUTLOOKADDIN oa where b.ID = oa.BOOKINGID and oa.GUID is null)
```

When i enter the Query to the SQLManagement Field, it returns a result.

This is the Main function

```
  public void start()
            {
                String SQLQuery = "SELECT b.ID,b.VERANSTALTER, b.SERIENBOOKUID, (select oa.ORIGINALDATE from OUTLOOKADDIN oa where oa.BOOKINGID = b.ID and oa.GUID is null) as ORIGINALDATE , rr.VON ,rr.BIS, b.THEMA, b.STORNO, ra.BEZEICHNUNG, et.BEZEICHNUNG as ETAGE,geb.ADRESSE, st.NAME as STADT"
                                + " from BUCHUNG b"
                                + " JOIN RESERVIERUNGRAUM rr on rr.BUCHUNG_ID = b.ID"
                                + " JOIN RAUM ra on ra.ID = rr.RAUM_ID"
                                + " JOIN ETAGE et on et.ID = ra.ETAGE_ID"
                                + " JOIN GEBAEUDE geb on geb.ID = ra.GEBAEUDE_ID"
                                + " JOIN STADT st on st.ID = ra.STADT_ID"
                                + " WHERE b.UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN " + oh.DatToDBISO(oldDate) + " AND getdate() AND b.BOOKVERNR = 0"
                                + " AND b.ID = (select distinct oa.BOOKINGID from OUTLOOKADDIN oa where b.ID = oa.BOOKINGID and oa.GUID is null)";
                SqlDataReader reader = oh.getSQLDR(SQLQuery);

                List<BookingUpdate> bookingUpdateList = new List<BookingUpdate>();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                log.Debug("not empty");
                }
                else
                {
                log.Debug("empty");
                }
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    BookingUpdate buObject = new BookingUpdate();
                    Int32 SerienBookUID = 0; ;

                    if (reader["SERIENBOOKUID"] != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                    log.Debug("b2");
                        SerienBookUID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["SERIENBOOKUID"]);
                    }

...
}
```

This is the Helper function which connects to SQL

```
 public SqlDataReader getSQLDR(string query)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        try
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            return reader;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Debug("Fehler beim übergeben des SQLDATAReaders :" + ex.Message);
        }
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: you need to show c# side code

Comment: sorry, i edited my code

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is concatenating your query with the Date. If you are going to use concatenation then date value should be enclosed in single quotes, so this:

```
b.UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN " + oh.DatToDBISO(oldDate) + " AND getdate() ....
```

should be

```
b.UPDATE_DATE BETWEEN '" + oh.DatToDBISO(oldDate) + "' AND getdate()
```

But **a better option** would be to use [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) and pass that parameter with your query, this will not only save you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) but also let you pass the date object without worrying about its presentation format.